# FontFamily import does not work with C# Xamarin in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, fonts

I am trying to import the "Lobster-Regular.ttf" https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lobster font and use it in my application but it doesn't work/doesn't show up in my android emulator.

I follow the guidelines specified in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts. See below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WeatherApp.MainPage"
             BackgroundImageSource="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5863622.jpg">

    <StackLayout Padding="20,20,20,20">
        <Label Text="Weatherized" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="30" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
               TextColor="White" FontFamily="Lobster"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

I've also used the following in the assembly file:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
[assembly: ExportFont("Lobster-Regular.ttf", Alias = "Lobster")]
```

I've downloaded the font file and put in a folder called "Resources" within my project solution.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you 1) set the font as an embedded resource 2) try using a ' ', instead of '-', for spacing. an example of this would be `[assembly: ExportFont("Lobster Regular.ttf", Alias = "Lobster")]` 3) rename the font file to `LobsterRegular` - sometimes spacing can cause problems 4) update your Xamarin.Forms version to the latest, try closing and reopening your solution 5) if that doesn't work you can use a custom renderer to set the font family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you can try is instead of using a dash (-) to indicate spacing you can try using ' '. An example of this would be the following code:

```
[assembly: ExportFont("Lobster Regular.ttf", Alias = "Lobster")] // notice the space
```

If that doesn't work - try removing all spaces in the name as that can cause some problems. Rename it to `LobsterRegular.ttf`.

The second thing you can do is try setting the font to an embedded resource **if you haven't already** (many people forget this step) -
I had the same problem as you - I set the .ttf file's build action as an 'embedded resource' and it worked.

[image]

If that doesn't work - try updating your Xamarin.Forms version to the **latest stable version.**

If you have tried everything and nothing has worked - the last option would be to use a custom renderer that can set the font family:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Button), typeof(CustomButtonRenderer))]
namespace Custombutton.Droid
{
    class CustomButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        public CustomButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets, "Lobster-Regular.ttf");
                Control.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Bold);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to go down this route - remember to place the .ttf file in your Android application.